# ETH sendSignedTransaction

Tags: ethereum, blockchain, solidity, smartcontracts

I Try to use @ethereumjs/tx to sign Transaction.
I want to send ETH from one address to second address.

```
....
const legacy = require('@ethereumjs/tx/dist/legacyTransaction');
const utils = require('web3-utils');
const {Personal} = require('web3-eth-personal');
....


    // https://docs.chainstack.com/reference/ethereum-sendrawtransaction
    const from = request.body.from;
    const to = request.body.to;
    const amount = '0.01';
    const passphrase = request.body.passphrase;
    const private_key = getPrivateKey(from, passphrase);

    // Define the gas limit
    const gasLimit = await new Web3Eth(local_provider).estimateGas({
        from: from,
        to: to,
    });

    // Get the transaction count for the sender address
    const nonce = await new Web3Eth(local_provider).getTransactionCount(from);

    // Define the transaction object
   const txData = {
        from,
        nonce: nonce,
        to,
        gasLimit: 21000,
        maxPriorityFeePerGas: utils.toHex(utils.toWei("5", "gwei")),
        maxFeePerGas: utils.toHex(utils.toWei("20", "gwei")),
        value: utils.toHex(utils.toWei('0.01', 'ether')),
    };

    const tx = legacy.Transaction.fromTxData(txData);
    const signedTx = tx.sign(private_key);
    const serializedTx = signedTx.serialize();
    const rawTransaction = '0x' + serializedTx.toString('hex');

    try {
        console.log(`Sending transaction...`);
        const result = await new Web3Eth(provider).sendSignedTransaction(rawTransaction);
        console.log(`Transaction hash: ${result.transactionHash}`);

    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
    }
```

> reason: 'err: insufficient funds for gas * price + value: address 0x2f1030396172F3e3d308819833fBbA655A9785a3 have 19175306697701238 want 16737889130546396655769049807908504612912 (supplied gas 21000)',

when I change to:

```
var tet = utils.toWei('0.01', 'ether');

const txData = {
    from,
    nonce: nonce,
    to,
    gasPrice: "0x" + parseInt(18000000000, 10).toString(16),
    gasLimit: "0x" + parseInt(90000, 10).toString(16),
    value: "0x" + parseInt(tet, 10).toString(16),
};
```

It's works Perfect!

My wish is not to set the gas fees and prices.
I wish to make it auto.

but without inject the gas, it will not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you submit a transaction without specifying the gas price, the transaction may not get executed or may experience significant delays. Because miners prioritize the transactions. Transactions with higher gas prices are more likely to be included in the next block becuase miners will make more money.

gas price is not constant. If the Ethereum network is very busy, gas prices might go very high. If you want gas price to be auto, then when the price is high, you will be paying so much money, unwittingly.